# PowerShell Set-Acl Method failed with unexpected error code 59

Tags: powershell

The following script works well when applying NTFS permissions to files and folders with one exception, I have a data set of 10 + TB's and it's producing an error, see below.

```
#This PS Script will add NTFS Permissions
#Create the ACE
#This command will display the NTFS Perms prior to making the NTFS Perm changes for comparison 
(Get-Acl -Path "$dir\\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS").Access | Format-Table -Autosize
#$identity = input the AD account to add user, use the below format
$identity = 'domain\username'
#$rights = This is the equivalent NTFS Permissions that are displayed on the Security tab 
$rights = 'Modify' #Other options: [enum]::GetValues('System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights')
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit' #Other options: [enum]::GetValues('System.Security.AccessControl.Inheritance')
$propagation = 'None' #Other options: [enum]::GetValues('System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags')
$type = 'Allow' #Other options: [enum]::GetValues('System.Securit y.AccessControl.AccessControlType')
$ACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation, $type)
#-Path is the path that will be modified with the new NTFS permissions, all folders, and files below this will obtain the NTFS perms 
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path "$dir\\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS"
$Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE)
Set-Acl -Path "$dir\\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS" -AclObject $Acl
#This command will display the changes after the NTFS Perms have been set so they can be compared to the per change Perms 
(Get-Acl -Path "$dir\\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS").Access | Format-Table -Autosize
```

**Error Message:**

```
Set-Acl : Method failed with unexpected error code 59.
At C:\Scripts\Adding_NTFS_Perms.ps1:18 char:1
+ Set-Acl -Path "$dir\\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (\\xx\xx\xxxx1...\xxxxx xxxxx:String) [Set-Acl], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

When performing this function using Windows Explorer on the same 10 + TB data set I see the screenshot message.

[Error Applying Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV0sc.png)

An error occurred while applying security information to :
\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS

An unexpected network error occurred.

Is there a way to bypass the error using the above script so that it completes?

Thank you in advance!

I've looked into error code 59 and not found any meaningful information as to why this is occurring.

Comment: Where in the script did you define variable `$dir` ?

Comment: Ah, it's not defined however that is interesting that the script still works. However not when it encounters an error.

Perhaps I should remove the $dir variable? Humm

Comment: Without the variable $dir the script still runs on my test directory and files. I still have a feeling this won't over come the issue. And I believe it has to do with some of the folders and file being > 256 characters... 

I will update the script to use \\?\UNC\xx\xx\xxxx1047\xxxxx\x\x\x\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST-NTFS-PERMS

Testing....

Comment: Ok, so the only issue that remains is how can I acknowledge/bypass/ignore files/folders that have been deleted/altered/etc. after the script is already running?

Comment: I don't really understand your last comment.. I presume you set the permissions on the **folder** where the files reside, or are you trying to set it for each file individually?? And, yes, if `$dir` is not defined, it simply is `$null` so unneeded, but in that case does not have any effect on the path as string

Comment: This script is setting the permissions on the folder, files are picking the perms up with no issues. So all good there... 

I'm running this script on a folder that has many changes occurring, specifically file deletions. When this script gets to a file that no longer exists it throws error code 59 and stops. Is there a way to account for this error and let the script continue?

Comment: Sure, you can append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the Set-Acl command, or if that doesn't help, do that part inside a try..catch block. Then set `-ErrorAction Stop` to the Set-Acl command and in the catch block do nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately that option just allows the script to quit without intervention.

Comment: Looks like you need to run the script when no user is making changes like in the middle of the night (scheduled task) or when everyone is on Christmas holidays.

Comment: I wish that were possible. :-(